# behavior of colon operator (:) with matrix or vector arguments

Tags: matlab

We all know the matlab colon operator to create a linear sequence, i.e.

```
1:5 = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Now I found that the arguments of the colon operator can also be applied to vectors or matrices. However I do not understand the definition behind.

Examples

```
[1 2 3 4]:5 == [1 2 3 4 5]

[1 2; 3 4]:3 == [1 2 3]
```

Why is this?

The second argument can be vector or matrix as well.

Ultimately I would like to understand sequences such as

```
1:2:3:4:5
```

which is fully legal in matlab and `[1 5]` by the way!

Note `1:2:3:4:5:6` is left associative i.e. parsed as `((1:2:3):4:5):6`.

So what is the behavior for the colon operator with matrix/vector arguments?

EDIT: corrected the statement of left associativity.

Comment: In my experience (I haven't searched the documentation), `[a b c]:[d e; f g]` is equivalent to `a:d`. That is, the colon picks the first element of each vector or matrix

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yes, I can experimentally confirm. I didn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [documentation](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) for the colon operator says:

> If you specify nonscalar arrays, MATLAB interprets j:i:k as j(1):i(1):k(1).

Your first example is interpreted as `1:3`, the second as `1:5`

Expressions with more than two `:` are parsed left-associative:

```
a:b:c:d:e==(a:b:c):d:e
```

.

```
    >> 1:2:3:4:5

ans =

     1     5
```